# Understanding IOC Container Injection

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring and not able to understand when to instantiate the class with new operator and when by using spring container.
example i found a code

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;  
public class Test {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  
    int status=dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",35000));  
    System.out.println(status);  

    int status=dao.updateEmployee(new Employee(102,"Sonoo",15000)); 
    System.out.println(status); 


    Employee e=new Employee(); 
    e.setId(102); 
    int status=dao.deleteEmployee(e); 
    System.out.println(status);

}  

}
```

i am using jdbc template. i have a doubt why we have new to instatiate employee class instead we should have used (Employee)ctx.getBean("employee"). using new operator would create dependency?
Pls help

Comment: Domain class should be instantiated with new operator. And you can let Spring create objects for you which are defined by you as Beans. You can do `(Employee)ctx.getBean("employee")` only if there is bean defined in your `applicationContext.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ProSpring book,

"Of the applications that we have built using Spring,
the only objects that are consistently not managed by Spring are domain objects. (Even though in Spring
it’s possible to have Spring manage domain objects by applying the @Component annotation to the classes
and assigning them with prototype scope, most of the time we will choose to manage domain objects
within the application.) The reason for this is that, practically, Spring does not need to be involved with
domain objects. Generally, you create many instances of your domain objects using the new() operator
and perform processing either in the service or data access layer. Although Spring also supports the
injection of new instance of domain objects every time it was requested (by using the bean scope
prototype), generally developers will not adopt this approach since typically domain objects do not take
advantage of Dependency Injection, because they generally have few dependencies outside of the DOM
itself, and they don’t require much configuration."

So, yes you could create beans of type Employee but then they wil have to be defined as prototype as be default all beans in spring are singletons. because there can be many employees and their objects, you obviously cannot have Employee as a singleton.  but your concentration as to the utilization of spring features should be much more than managing domain objects.

Comment: Thanks alot @user3138997

Answer (score 0):

The Spring IOC container is at the core of the Spring Framework. The container will create the objects, wire them together, configure them, and manage their complete lifecycle from creation till destruction.The IoC container gets informations/metadata either from XML or by Java annotations, or by Java code.

Yeah you can create Employee bean in your spring context xml file and make sure scope is prototype as

```
<bean id="employee" class="com.mycompany.Employee" scope="prototype"/>
```

so that on every request of Employee bean, you will get a new object Employee.

There are other scopes of beans

- singleton : This scopes the bean definition to a single instance per Spring IoC container (default).
- request : On every HTTP request a new bean will created and delivered.
- prototype : on every request(api request) a new bean will be created.
- session :  This scope a bean definition to an HTTP session.

Note : It is not recomemded to create beans for database model class.because your persistent layer will take care of it.